# Dimension of subspace defined by matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How would one go about determining the dimension of the subspace:

$$
A \in M_{33} : AX = -XA, \forall X \in M_{33}
$$

my first intuition is to get an arbitrary matrix A and X and get AX and -XA, equate them and determine any restrictions.This definitely seems too long a method to be viable. Any hints or help is appreciated.

Comment: Might be more clear if you put braces around your set comprehension $\{ \cdot \}$

Comment: Are you wanting $A$ to anti-commute with all $3 \times 3$ matrices? Or just a specific one? I suppose the former would mean that $A = 0$.

Comment: for a given $X$ a first step would be to conjugate the equation with a matrix $P$ chosen to make $PXP^{-1}$ as simple as possible.

Comment: I am not sure what it means to conjugate the equation. I am sure this problem can be solved using an "easier" method.

Comment: In its current incarnation, $A  = 0$ is the only possibility. Since $X=I$ gives $A = -A$. (Unless you are working in characteristic 2 in which $A = -A$ is true for all matrices.)

Comment: "for some $X$" is a much more interesting problem (and not so "easy")